# Split a dictionary of lists based on partition values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Suppose, I have have dictionary like:

```
student_info = {'Student_id':[85, 47, 49, 56, 23, 61], 'Student_age':[91, 116, 913, 49, 65, 76]}

partition value = [1,2,3]
```

How do i split the dictionary keeping the keys intact but values split based on partition value to something like:

```
[{'Student_id':[85], 'Student_age':[91]},{'Student_id':[47, 49], 'Student_age':[116, 913 ]},{'Student_id':[56, 23, 61], 'Student_age':[49, 65, 76]}]
```

Also, what's the most optimized/fastest way?

Comment: Why do you have a dictionary of lists instead of a list of dictionaries? That's generally much easier to deal with, since all the related data is together.

Comment: Anyway, loop through the partition list, and make slices of the lists in the dictionary of the appropriate lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Try looping through and appending the appropriate sized chunk to the output:

```
i=0
output = list()
for size in partition_value:
    output.append({k: v[i:i+size] for k,v in student_info.items()})
    i+=size

>>> output
[{'Student_id': [85], 'Student_age': [91]},
 {'Student_id': [47, 49], 'Student_age': [116, 913]},
 {'Student_id': [56, 23, 61], 'Student_age': [49, 65, 76]}]
```